# Saving Canvas Image at high resolution

Tags: android, image, canvas, bitmap

I am creating an Android app where a user can draw, add text, or image on to the canvas.

After the user has finished editing on th canvas there is an option for saving.

When I try to save that as an image, the resulting output image is of very low resolution.

```java
canvas.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);                
canvas.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
Bitmap bitmap = canvas.getDrawingCache();
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
File file = new File(path+"/image.jpg");
FileOutputStream ostream;
try {
    file.createNewFigle();
    ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, ostream);
    ostream.flush();
    ostream.close();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "image saved", 5000).show();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error", 5000).show();
}
```

I want the image to be saved as A3 300dpi. Is there any possible way?

Answer (score 1):

Try to save text, images and all drawing as objects and when the user clicks the save button create a new bitmap with required resolution and translate the current canvas to the required one

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because of using bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, ostream); use PNG instread of JPEG
Hope you be ok

Comment: if you not ok please try like this one
Bitmap bitmap =
            Bitmap.createBitmap(image.width,image.height,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

Comment: sorry i forget full sample code , try as the following if you not ok please try like this one
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(image.width, image.height,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        my_journal_ss_item.draw(canvas);
        try {
          File file = new File(file_path);
          FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
          bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
          fOut.flush();
          fOut.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }